# How to setattr in ctypes.pointer.contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm using a custom ctypes in my code, but I found that I can setattr nothing in ctypes.pointer.contents. See this code:

```
import ctypes

class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("value", ctypes.c_int), )

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.vars_len = 1
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

t = Test(5)
pt = ctypes.pointer(t)
print(f"t.vars_len:{t.vars_len}")
print(hasattr(pt.contents, "vars_len"))
pt.contents.vars_len = "hello"
print(hasattr(pt.contents, "vars_len"))
```

output:

```
t.vars_len:1
False
False
```

Neither the definition at instantiation time nor the setattr take effect.
So I wonder how to setattr in ctypes.pointer.contents?
I want to realize a custom ctypes, which is a variable length point, has "vars_len" attr to discripe the length of data, but I don't want to modify the ctype's _fields_.
Or is there another way?

Comment: "I don't want to modify the ctype's `_fields_`" Is there any reason why? If you don't want to modify the ``Structure``, is there any reason why you need the metadata *on* the structure instead of, say, an external ``dict``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Because I want to send data to c by redis, if I modify _fields_, I can't simply and directly convert my data to my structure.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Emmm.. Wait! Thanks for your reminding. I seem to have made a mistake about something. If a struct contain a point of variable length array, it will also contian the length of the array. I shouldn't worry about that. Sorry, I didn't figure that out when I was designing this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.  `Test` wraps a memory structure.  `pt` wraps a pointer to the memory structure itself, not the `Test` object.  When you access `pt.contents` a new `Test` object is created and returned to wrap memory structure at that address each time it is accessed.  It's not the original `Test` object where the attribute was stored.

Note the IDs of the objects are all different below:

```py
import ctypes

class Test(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("value", ctypes.c_int), )

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        self.vars_len = 1
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

t = Test(5)
pt = ctypes.pointer(t)
print(id(t))
a = pt.contents
b = pt.contents
c = pt.contents
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(id(c))
```

Output:

```
2453287249216
2453287249472
2453275065920
2453287248448
```

The memory stucture would need to have the length in the data itself and referred to by `_fields_`.